# Brownie deploy --- ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, brownie

I am by far an expert, but more like a hobby. Having issues with a deploy script in Brownie. When running the script, I get a simple ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0). Was suspecting it might have something to do with not being able to read the csv file properly, but even with the "coins" variable hard-coded, I get the same error. I am totally lost.

here is my deploy.py code and the response I get. Any hint would be much appreciated.

```
import os

from brownie import bullzeye, accounts
from brownie.convert import to_address
from brownie.network.gas.strategies import GasNowStrategy
from pathlib import Path
import requests
import pandas as pd

PROJECT_DIR = Path(__file__).parent.parent
CHAIN_ID = 1
TOKENS_LIST_URL = f"https://apiv5.paraswap.io/tokens/{CHAIN_ID}"


# Fetch the token list if it doesn't exist
tokens_fp = PROJECT_DIR.joinpath(f"data/tokens-chain-{CHAIN_ID}.csv")
if not tokens_fp.exists():
    tokens_fp.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    tokens = requests.get(TOKENS_LIST_URL).json()["tokens"]
    tokens_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(tokens, index="address")
    tokens_df.index = tokens_df.index.map(to_address)
    tokens_df.to_csv(tokens_fp)
else:
    tokens_df = pd.read_csv(tokens_fp, index_col="address")

# acct = accounts.load(1)

tx_params = {
    "from": accounts.add(os.getenv("PRIVATE_KEY")),
    "gas_price": GasNowStrategy("standard"),
}

# Helper functions
def get_token_addresses(*symbols):
    """Get a list of token addresses given their symbols"""
    addresses = []
    for symbol in symbols:
        addr = tokens_df[tokens_df["symbol"] == symbol].index[0]
        addresses.append(to_address(addr))
    return addresses



def main():
    coins = get_token_addresses("USDT", "WBTC", "WETH")
    bullzeye.deploy(coins, tx_params)
```

response I get is this:

```
brownie run scripts/deploy.py --network goerli
Brownie v1.19.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum

BullzEyeProject is the active project.

Running 'scripts/deploy.py::main'...
  File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 51, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "brownie/project/scripts.py", line 110, in run
    return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
  File "./scripts/deploy.py", line 46, in main
    bullzeye.deploy(coins, tx_params)
  File "brownie/network/contract.py", line 549, in __call__
    return tx["from"].deploy(
  File "brownie/network/account.py", line 510, in deploy
    receipt, exc = self._make_transaction(
  File "brownie/network/account.py", line 727, in _make_transaction
    raise VirtualMachineError(e) from None
  File "brownie/exceptions.py", line 93, in __init__
    raise ValueError(str(exc)) from None
ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my limited understanding, when you are calling deploy(), 'gas_price' only supports integers.

Account transactions do appear to support gas strategy objects, but I believe deploy() goes down a different path.
https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/v1.13.4/core-gas.html

For deploy(), _make_transaction() is called in brownie's account.py which requires an int (expressed in Wei) for gas_price.

This will work:
`bullzeye.deploy({'from': account, 'gas_price': 10000000})`